# SQLite-PCL : Accessing my own created table?

Tags: sqlite, xamarin

I'm referring to SQLite-PCL tutorial here: https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/an-introduction-to-xamarinforms-and-sqlite--cms-23020

I'm very new to SQLite, so I'm lacking in knowledge in lots of basic things - I have tried Googling, can't understand most of it.

1. Is the call to new SQLiteConnection actually opens up the database or just saying that "the road to the database has been established, whether you access it or not is up to you"?
2. How do I check if there's already existing database in the devices? And if there is, how do I access it? I have Googled this, but it all seems to be a bit extreme - can't I just call simple OPEN the database?
3. Is it okay to have multiple SQLiteConnection instances to the same database, if I can be sure that I'm not going to do multiple transaction at the same time?
4. After I have INSERT into the database, close the app, open up the app back - how do I make sure that there is database created in previous session? Any way to debug this? Because I have no idea if the database is there or not, and I don't know how to access it either..

Answer (score 0):

1. SQLiteConnection returns a connection object that is used to make subsequent queries
2. use File.Exists to see if the db file is already present
3. Yes
4. Again, use File exists to see if the db file is physically present

Xamarin's [ToDo](https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/xamarin-forms/Todo/) sample provides a good overview of using SQLite with Forms.

Comment: Thanks for the link! I really needed that. I have at least got the basic functionality working. Now to do something fancy... ;)